# How to avoid repeated "each other" and "statistics" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy, repetition

How can you avoid repeating "each other" and "statistics" in the sentence below?

> We're a tight-knit group of students, lecturers and professionals who
>   answer each other's statistics questions and help each other with
>   statistics projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Help can be used for both questions and projects.

> We're a tight-knit group of students, lecturers and professionals who help each other with statistics questions and projects.

Comment: So, they are from a different area of study than statistics?

Comment: Lambie - what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

What about the following? Eliminates the need to say 'each others'' twice.

> We're a tight-knit group of students, lecturers, and professionals that answer questions about statistics and help with each others' projects related to statistics.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sorry, I edited it, although not thoroughly since an answer was already chosen. I wish stack exchange sites would have their rules more easily accessible - where would be appropriate to ask for that?

Comment: On [Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/) would be fine, but while we have no objections to making rules easier to access, it's unfortunately not a very easy project for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score -1):

We're a tight-knit group of students, lecturers and professionals in statistics who help each other with questions and projects.